# AnimatePresence and exit animation won't fire

Tags: javascript, framer-motion

I'm trying to make an animated countdown clock using `framer motion`.

I understand that any child of `<AnimatePresence/>` with a unique key should animate into and out of the parent. However, I just can't get the exit to work. Is it the way I'm injecting/replacing the spans?

```
<AnimatePresence>
  <div>
    {timeString.split("").map((val, i) => (
      <motion.span
        key={val + i}
        initial={{ y: 50, opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
        exit={{ y: -50, opacity: 0 }} <--- this doesn't seem to work
        transition={{
          x: { duration: 1, type: "spring", stiffness: 300, damping: 30 },
          opacity: { duration: 0.5 }
        }}
      >
        {val}
      </motion.span>
    ))}
  </div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

[Codesandbox WIP](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animted-clock-wrjql)

[Documentation](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/)

EDIT: to clarify, i'm trying to get the numbers to enter from the bottom and leave via the top. Currently, they only enter from the bottom and there is no exit animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting, I realized it's because there's a `h1` tag inside of `<AnimatePresence>`. It isn't mentioned in the docs but it looks like `<AnimatePresence>` looks for specific child components. Adding in elements like `span` or `div` without using the `<motion>` component bugs it out.

There are still imperfections to get `exit` looking perfect, but I've added a Codesandbox link that **should** unblock you.

Codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animted-clock-forked-hyhnh?file=/src/App.js:445-465)

P.S. `framer-motion` is a neat library thanks for sharing! Never knew it existed.

Comment: I actually can't believe it was that simple. A real facepalm moment. Of course, it makes perfect sense they would have to be direct children! Thanks

Comment: No sweat. It's an honor to help someone with 20k+ points haha

Comment: It's a great library! I've discovered it for NextJS page transitions and it's super easy to use.

Comment: Now I just have to make the animation look better :)